# updating data on tree data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree, antd

guys.
I am dealing with tree data right now, but got a problem.
Here is my sample code.

```
const dummyTreeData = [
    {
      title: 'parent 1',
      key: '1',
      children: [
        {
          title: 'parent 1-0',
          key: '1-0',
          disabled: true,
          children: [
            {
              title: 'leaf',
              key: '1-0-0',
              disableCheckbox: true,
            },
            {
              title: 'leaf',
              key: '1-0-1',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          title: 'parent 1-1',
          key: '1-1',
          children: [
            {
              title: <span style={{ color: '#1677ff' }}>sss</span>,
              key: '1-1-1',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },

    {
      title: 'parent 2',
      key: '2',
      children: [
        {
          title: 'parent 2-0',
          key: '2-0',
          disabled: true,
          children: [
            {
              title: 'leaf',
              key: '2-0-0',
              disableCheckbox: true,
            },
            {
              title: 'leaf',
              key: '2-0-1',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          title: 'parent 2-1',
          key: '2-1',
          children: [
            {
              title: <span style={{ color: '#1677ff' }}>sss</span>,
              key: '2-1-1',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

How can I modify values inside tree data?
I am using useState to manipulate the data. It is ok to update the first(parent) title value based on key value but what if I wanna access to children? Do I have to map it inside map?
maybe it is ok to access the first children, but what if I need to access to children's children and more?

I am using antd tree, so please tell me some good solutions to solve my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code should work for your example data. if you have more nested children, then you need to map over them.

```
 setTree((prev) => {
  return prev.map((tree) => {
    if (tree.key === '2') {
      return {
        ...tree,
        title: 'updated title',
        children: tree.children.map((child) => {
          if (child.key === '2-0') {
            return {
              ...child,
              title: 'parent 2-0 updated',
              children: child.children.map((nestedchild) => {
                if (nestedchild.key === '2-0-0') {
                  return {
                    ...nestedchild,
                    title: 'leaf updated',
                  };
                }
                return nestedchild;
              }),
            };
          }
          return child;
        }),
      };
    }
    return tree;
  });
});
```